# Is the order of extension installation guaranteed in a package?

Tags: jinstaller

I have a package with a component and plugin, and I need to ensure that the component is installed before the plugin during the installation process (as the plugin installer has a dependency on a database table installed by the component). Does anyone know if that's the default behaviour (alphabetical -- the Joomla! way?)?

If not, is there a way to control the order, maybe the order extensions are listed in the `pkg_mycomponent.xml` file?

Answer (score 3):

> If not, is there a way to control the order, maybe the order extensions are listed in the pkg_mycomponent.xml file?

Yes, extensions are installed in the same order they're listed in package manifest file.

Comment: Thanks, Sharky!